# HttpContext in MVC Attributes - threading issues?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, httpcontext

I had my NHibernate session management setup like follows:

```
    protected MvcApplication()
    {
        BeginRequest += delegate
                            {
                                NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.OpenSession();
                             };
        EndRequest += delegate
                            {

                                NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.CloseSession();
                            };
    }
```

And for when I needed to save to the database, I made an ActionFilterAttribute that looked like this:

public class TransactionAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private ITransaction _currentTransaction;

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _currentTransaction = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.CurrentSession.Transaction;
        _currentTransaction.Begin();
    }


    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (_currentTransaction.IsActive)
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception == null)
                _currentTransaction.Commit();
            else
            {
                _currentTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
        _currentTransaction.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and then I could just add [Transaction] to my action method. This seemed to work in initial testing, but I then I tried using at HttpWebRequest to call an action method from another app multiple times and I had issues. Testing with Fiddler I setup a POST request and then fired them off in quick succession and it showed up the following:
[image: WebRequests]

THe red ones are various errors that I believe is to do with threading.

My NHibernateSessionManager uses the HTtpContext to store the session like this:

```
    public ISession CurrentSession
    {
        get { return (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"] = value; }
    }
```

So, to fixed it, I moved my Transaction code into my BeginRequest and EndRequest methods - and then I could fire off heaps in succession.

My question is - why did this fix it? I would have thought that I would have had something similar to this:
Begin Request - opens session
OnActionExecuting - starts transaction
action code 
OnActionExecuted - commits transaction
End Request - closes session

and that this would be unique to each request, so it shouldn't interfere with one another, because there should be a different HttpContext for each request shouldn't there? Or are they shared or something??

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from the [release notes of ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#RTM-BC):

> In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC,
>   action filters were created per
>   request except in a few cases. This
>   behavior was never a guaranteed
>   behavior but merely an implementation
>   detail and the contract for filters
>   was to consider them stateless. In
>   ASP.NET MVC 3, filters are cached more
>   aggressively. Therefore, any custom
>   action filters which improperly store
>   instance state might be broken.

This basically means that the `_currentTransaction` instance you have in your action filter might not be what you think it is. So be careful how/when is this property injected => it is not clear from the code you have shown.